# Mutate and replace few columns at once

Tags: r, dplyr

I have df such as:

```
  outc  task  prevt 
  <fct> <fct> <fct> 
1 los   fre   rep   
2 los   fre   swi   
3 los   ins   rep   
4 los   ins   swi   
5 win   fre   rep   
6 win   fre   swi   
7 win   ins   rep   
8 win   ins   swi
```

I want to replace values in column task and prevt, depending on the value in each of these columns. For example, if task is 'fre' AND prevt is 'rep', then task should be changed to 'ins' and prev should be changed to 'swi'. The key thing is that I need to change it all at once, as if I do it one after another, then the result would be different from what I want. So it seemed like easy task to do with mutate and replace:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(task = replace(task, task == 'fre' & prevt == 'rep', 'ins'),
         prevt = replace(prevt, task == 'fre' & prevt == 'rep', 'swi'))
```

But for some reason, only the first part of mutate works in this case, i.e. task column is changed, but prevt column is not.

```
  outc  task  prevt
  <fct> <fct> <fct>
1 los   ins   rep  
2 los   fre   swi  
3 los   ins   rep  
4 los   ins   swi  
5 win   ins   rep  
6 win   fre   swi  
7 win   ins   rep  
8 win   ins   swi
```

If I change second part to some non-conditional value (e.g. prevt = '1'), then it works.

```
df %>% 
  mutate(task = replace(task, which(task == 'fre' & prevt == 'rep'), 'ins'),
         prevt = '1')

  outc  task  prevt
  <fct> <fct> <chr>
1 los   ins   1    
2 los   fre   1    
3 los   ins   1    
4 los   ins   1    
5 win   ins   1    
6 win   fre   1    
7 win   ins   1    
8 win   ins   1
```

So for some reason two replace does not work within mutate. Can you please help me what could I do in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `base R` option would be to create an object with the logical condition first (so that it won't change later) and then use `Map` to replace the columns with the corresponding values

```
i1 <- with(df, task == "fre" & prevt == "rep")
df[-1] <- Map(function(x, i) replace(x, i1, i),  df[-1], c("ins", "swi"))
```

---

Or following the same logic in OP's code, create the logical condition first and then use that

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
     mutate(i1 = task == "fre" & prevt == "rep", # create logical column 
            task = replace(task, i1, "ins"), 
            prevt = replace(prevt, i1, "swi")) %>% 
     select(-i1) # remove the logical column
```

Comment: Thanks, I like the second solution. However, what if I actually have more conditions which I need to include in mutate at once? So, e.g. not only task == "fre" & prevt == "rep", but also  task == "fre" & prevt == "swi" (and in 2nd case replace would do something else).

Comment: Ok nevermind, solved - I had to define my few conditions in first mutate, and do the actual replaces in second mutate. Thanks!